# Deleting a user in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In buddy press admin want to delete a user with his related information from the system. Related info like friends, friend request, messages, notifications,waves etc.. How do I do this. Is there any plugin available. Or Should I write full code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function:

```
wp_delete_user( $user_id );
```

OR

```
bp_core_delete_account( $user_id)
```